# obtain number row in access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

SQL Server:

```
SELECT col1, col2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order BY col1) AS intRow FROM Table1
```

What is the equivalent code in Access?

Comment: See answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17279417/122139.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no equivalent. If you want a sequence, one way to do it is to create a table with an AutoNumber column. Another way would be something like:

```
Select ..,
    , (
        Select Count(*)
        From MyTable As T1
        Where T1.PrimaryKeyCol < T.PrimaryKeyCol
        ) + 1 As Seq
From MyTable As T
```

However, if the table is large, that may not perform well.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is ANSI, and vendor implementation is increasing.  But the `SELECT COUNT(...` subselect output will resemble `DENSE_RANK` output rather than ROW_NUMBER because duplicates will get the same `seq` value.