# Dynamically creating Columns from rows Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am relatively new to Access and I have a table that has `AuthorName`, `BookTitle`, and `CoAuthor`.  `AuthorName` and `BookTitle` are a composite key.

Currently the query pulls information like:

```
AuthorName---------BookTitle------CoAuthor

Steven King--------Dark Half------Peter Straub

Steven King--------Dark Half------John Doe

James Patterson----Another Time

Jeff Hanson--------Tales of Time---Joe Smith
```

I would like it to read (dynamically) if possible

```
AuthorName---------BookTitle---------CoAuthor1--------CoAuthor2

Steven King----------Dark Half--------Peter Straub-----Joe Doe

James Patterson----Another Time

Jeff Hanson----------Tales of Time----Joe Smith
```

So if there is another author that is later added, a third column for CoAuthor would appear.

Is this possible with VBA or SQL?

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking goes against the whole point of using a relational database; in short, you should design your tables in a way that minimizes (rather eliminates) the need to redesign the tables. I suggest you read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Your question is, as a matter of fact, an example that I use very frequently when I teach about databases: ***How would you design a database to hold all the information about books and authors***. The scenarios are:

- A book can have one or more authors
- An author may have written one or more books

So, this is a *many-to-many* relation, and there's a way to design such a database.

First, design a table for the authors:

- tbl_authors

  - author_idd (primary key, numeric, preferibly autonumeric)
  - first_name (String)
  - last_name (String)

Then, design a table for the books:

- tbl_books

  - book_id (primary key, numeric, preferibly autonumeric)
  - book_title (String)

And finally, a third table is needed to relate authors and books:

- tbl_books_authors

  - book_id (primary key, numeric)
  - author_id (primary key, numeric)
  - main_author (boolean: "Yes" if it is the main author, "No" otherwise)

(Both fields must be part of the primary key)

And now, the main question: How to query for books and its authors?

Asuming the above design, you could write an SQL query to get the full list of books and its authors:

```
select book_title, first_name, last_name
from 
    tbl_authors as a
    inner join tbl_books_authors as ba on a.authorId = ba.authorId
    inner join tbl_books as b on ba.bookId = b.bookId
```

This way, you'll have something like this:

```
book_title | first_name | last_name
-----------+------------+-----------
book1      | John       | Doe
book1      | Jane       | Doe
book2      | John       | Doe
book2      | Peter      | Who
book3      | Jane       | Doe
book4      | Peter      | Who
book5      | John       | Doe
book5      | Jane       | Doe
book5      | Peter      | Who
book5      | Jack       | Black
```

Why is this design better than your original idea?

- Because you won't need to alter the structure of your tables to add another author
- Because you don't know *a priori* how many authors a book can have
- Because you avoid redundancy in your database
- Because, with this design, you'll be able to use front-end tools (like Access forms and reports, or other tools) to create almost any arraingment from this data.

Further reading:

- [The Access Web](http://access.mvps.org/access/) (specially ["The Ten Commandments of Access"](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm))

---

***Minor update***

This kind of design will help you avoid lots and lots of headaches in the future, because you won't need to alter your tables every time you add a third or fourth author. I learned about database normalization some years ago reading "Running Access 97" by Jon Viescas (this is not a commercial, it's just a reference ;) )... an old book, yes, but it has a very good introduction on the topic.

Now, after you have normalized your database, you can use pivot queries to get what you need (as noted in the [answer posted by Conrad Frix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540926/dynamically-creating-colums-from-rows-access-2010/24541787#24541787)).

Comment: Specifically, with a structure like this it will be possible to use an Access cross-tab query to get the output you may be looking for.

Comment: +1 for the overall message, but the purpose of [mainAuthor] is unclear. Putting it in the [tbl_authors] table implies that a given author will be "the main author" for every work in which s/he is involved. (And what does it mean if two "main authors" work on the same book?) My instincts tell me that [mainAuthor] should be in the [tbl_books_authors] table.

Comment: @Barranka excellent summary but why the switching between camelCase and snake_case? The OP framed it in PascalCase. Whatever the choice, I'd not mix multiple conventions in one application.

Comment: @JeremyCook Maybe its just a matter of being self-taught in some topics... I just find it comfortable naming tables in snake_case and fields in camelCase... but yes, you are right (I am violating the 3rd of the [Ten Commandments of Access](http://access.mvps.org/access/tencommandments.htm))... correcting

Comment: @JeremyCook it's possible to do a cross-tab without redesign.

Comment: @ConradFrix yes, you are right... however I intend to make the point that a normalized database can avoid lots and lots of pain in the future

Comment: @ConradFrix true, I wasn't suggesting it didn't, only that what Barranka proposed will support its use. Guess I should have thrown the word "also" or something in there.

Comment: @Barranka I certainly agree that this strucutre badly needs a redesign and your answer does a good job explaining why the OP should do that. Sometimes however that can't be done for various reasons. As an aside I'd use `author_sort` instead of `main_author` since it allows for "billing" order to be maintained in the case of 3 or more authors.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, I guess that I oversimplified my question, I do have multiple tables and the query results were not what I wanted.  I apologize for the confusion.  However the information provided is still great to remember.

Answer (score 3):

If your table had type like below

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
|   AuthorName    |   BookTitle   |   CoAuthor   |   Type    |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| Steven King     | Dark Half     | Peter Straub | CoAuthor1 |
| Steven King     | Dark Half     | John Doe     | CoAuthor2 |
| James Patterson | Another Time  |              | CoAuthor1 |
| Jeff Hanson     | Tales of Time | Joe Smith    | CoAuthor1 |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

it would be a pretty simple transform

```
TRANSFORM First(Books.CoAuthor) AS FirstOfCoAuthor
SELECT Books.AuthorName, Books.BookTitle
FROM Books
GROUP BY Books.AuthorName, Books.BookTitle
PIVOT Books.Type;
```

Since it doesn't we need to create it on the fly by first assigning a number to each row simulating [ROW_NUMBER OVER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18753575/119477) and then transforming. On large data sets this may be quite slow

```
TRANSFORM First(b.coauthor) AS firstofcoauthor 
SELECT b.authorname, 
       b.booktitle 
FROM   (SELECT authorname, 
               booktitle, 
               coauthor, 
               'CoAuthor' & k AS Type 
        FROM   (SELECT b.authorname, 
                       b.booktitle, 
                       b.coauthor, 
                       Count(*) AS K 
                FROM   books AS b 
                       LEFT JOIN books AS b1 
                              ON b.authorname = b1.authorname 
                WHERE  [b].[coauthor] <= [b1].[coauthor] 
                        OR (( ( b1.coauthor ) IS NULL )) 
                GROUP  BY b.authorname, 
                          b.booktitle, 
                          b.coauthor) AS t) AS b 
GROUP  BY b.authorname, 
          b.booktitle 
PIVOT b.type
```

Comment: This is the answer :-) The other answer is useful info for beginners and reminders for the experienced.

Comment: Thank you for the information and great example of how to accomplish the task.  I would not have thought to use a crosstab query to get this done.  Thank you to all who gave their input.

Comment: @user3799282 If this reply answares your question coul'd you please mark it as answar by clicking the v on the left of the answar. It will become green v and mark your Q. as answared for all SO users. Thanks