# MS Access equivalent of ROW_NUMBER() and OVER()

Tags: sql, ms-access, lazy-loading

I've the following sql statement running in sql server-

```
SELECT Id,Name
       FROM
       (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Id DESC ) AS row, Id, Name from BRS 
       )
AS data WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

Now, I would like to implement same technique in MS Access database. But it gives syntax error for `ROW_NUMBER() and OVER()`

Is there any MS Access 2007 syntax of `ROW_NUMBER() and OVER()`?

Comment: Have a look at Gordon Linoff's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753368/row-number-in-access-select-statement).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I saw that. But that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    (Select Count(*) From BRS As B Where B.Id >= BRS.Id) As Row,
    BRS.Id, 
    BRS.Name
FROM 
    BRS
ORDER BY 
    BRS.Id DESC;
```

Result:

```
Id  Name    Row
10  Test    1
9   TestTwo 2
8   Thing   3
6   Another 4
5   Anyone  5
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to get next 5 records?

Comment: One method is to _select top 10_, then select from these those _not in select top 5_.