# SQL query for last transaction on MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I have a table with the following fields:

- Customerid
- Customerpaydate
- Amount

I need help in retrieving most recent transaction but no repetition in of customer ID.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: ORDER BY will let you order your data

Comment: but i dont want customer id to be repeated either. I tried Distinct but id's are repeated

Comment: A window function would work in SQL Server.  Check out MS Access equivalents for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753368/row-number-in-access-select-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull out the most recent transaction par customer, a correlated subquery should get the job done:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where customerpaydate = (
    select max(Customerpaydate) from mytable t1 where t1.customerid = t.customerid      
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the max paydate

```
 SELECT MAX(customerpaydate) as d 
 FROM table
```

This will give you the max paydate by customer

```
 SELECT customerid, max(customerpaydate) as d 
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY customerid
```

The will give you the most recent transaction

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 where customerpaydate = (SELECT MAX(customerpaydate) as d FROM table)
```

This will give you the most recent transaction of each customer

```
 SELECT *
 FROM TABLE
 JOIN (
    SELECT customerid, max(customerpaydate) as d 
    FROM TABLE 
    GROUP BY customerid
 ) AS S ON S.customerid = TABLE.customerid and S.d = TABLE.customerpaydate
```