# SQL for Middle Value Rather than MIN/MAX or FIRST/LAST

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a SQL function to return the middle value of three?

For example, assume I have a table with people who have three cars, sorted alphabetically by AutoMaker.

```
John: Ford
John: Honda
John: VW
```

then

```
MIN(AutoMaker) returns Ford.
MAX(AutoMaker) returns VW.
```

Is there a similar SQL function that will return Honda?

I am working with MS Access and Oracle.

Thank you.

Comment: look at `row_number` in Oracle. However, what would the result be if people have more than 3 cars? would you like to list out all the results that are not `min` and `max`?

Comment: select where not max and where not min ...

Comment: you mean the `MEDIAN` value?

Comment: I don't mean median value. These are text fields.

Comment: Yes, all of the results that are not min and max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No. It's too specific.

Longer answer: It's too specific. Hence, the "middle" in what you said is actually the second record. But if you had 5 records, it would be the third, and so on. If you need that in practice, just assign a row number to each row ([Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), [Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279320/row-numbers-in-query-result-using-microsoft-access)) and then select the ((n+1)/2)nd row (WHERE row_number = (n+1)/2).

PS - which is the middle row if you have 4 rows? :)

Comment: This data doesn't happen to have 4 rows. I only have three, and I need to get the middle one.

Answer (score 0):

The query could be something like this

```
select row_id, Field1   
FROM tbl 
where row_id  = (select cInt(count(Field1)/2) from tbl)
```

The problem in access is that you do not have a row_number you would need to add a row_id to the table and then populate row_id 1,2,3,4 (ordered on Field1)