# Create row_num column in Access SQL, order by field first

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a simple query that will take a table, order by the date field of that table and add a column that includes a row count. This is the easiest thing in T-SQL, but Access does not support the Row_Num() function.

So, let's say my "Dates" table looks like this:

```
ID       Date
1        02/01/2017
2        02/03/2017
3        01/27/2017
4        02/05/2017
5        02/01/2017
6        02/03/2017
```

And the result of my Access query should look like this:

```
ID       Date          RowNum
3        01/27/2017    1
1        02/01/2017    2
5        02/01/2017    3
2        02/03/2017    4
6        02/03/2017    5
4        02/05/2017    6
```

I have tried to find an answer to this question, but all the answers I have found seem to rely on the difference in the values of the ID field from one row to the next. So then I tried to apply the concepts I found (creating a column with a dcount where A.ID > ID) to the Date field, but then I get a count per date. But I need a count for every single date, even if there might be multiple dates that are the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could reference [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17303172/3844458) for `DCount function`

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, this Dcount solution works on the ID, but not on the date, when there can be multiple identical dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*,
       (select count(*) from dates as d2 where d2.date <= d.date) as rownum
from dates as d
order by d.date;
```

This is not very efficient, but on a small table it does accomplish what you want.  The simplest way, though, is probably to use a cursor over the table.

This assumes that the dates are distinct, as in the example data in the question.

EDIT:

On closer inspection, the dates are not unique.  So you can use multiple conditions:

```
select d.*,
       (select count(*)
        from dates as d2
        where d2.date < d.date or
              (d2.date = d.date and d2.id <= d.id)
       ) as rownum
from dates as d
order by d.date;
```

Comment: Will that work with two identical dates? Maybe there needs to be a reference to the ID?

Comment: This will only give me a new row number for each new Date. But I need a new row num for each row, no matter what the date.

Comment: @Tyler . . . I noticed that the sample data does have duplicate dates, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!