# MS Access Report Crashes in View Mode On Mouse Wheel

Tags: ms-access, crash, report, mousewheel

**I have an MS Access report that crashes when the mouse wheel is used to scroll through the report in view mode.**  I've been verbose.  **For a quicker version, read bold text only.**

Before I go further, when I say crashes Access, I mean a spinning wheel pops up and Access becomes unresponsive (i.e. "Not Responding").  The only way to get out of this state is to force Access to close.  No error codes or explanation are given.

This problem only occurs in report view mode.  If I open the report in design, layout, or print mode there are no issues.  The issue only occurs when using the mouse wheel.  Scrolling with the vertical scroll bar or arrow keys poses no problem.  This issue is repeatable across users on different machines with different mice.  Though it is likely we're both running Access 2016 and Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.  I have not configured any "on mouse wheel" vba code anywhere in the database.

The report itself contains ~20 fields, 2 very simple subreports (single tables with 2 columns liked off a single field on the main report), and a rather lengthy report body with 3 layers of grouping and roughly 150 rows sprinkled among the various groups.  The rows are retrieving longer memo fields (hundreds of characters per row).

In addition, **I have added a field that numbers each row (text box with control source=1, configured as a running sum "over all").  Oddly, if I delete the running sum text box, the problem goes away.  If I add it back again, the problem returns.**  This is the only calculated field in the report.  All of the other data originate from queries.  I should point out that the report worked fine with the field that numbered each row prior to adding the two subreports.  So it seems that the combination of counting from 1 to 150 + subreports is overwhelming Access.  [This is surprising to me given that my database is fairly small - 15-20 tables with less than 1000 rows total.]

[Configuration of text box that seems to be causing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ0vD.png)

**Has anyone seen this problem before?  Does anyone know of a work around I could use to number each row versus just storing the row number in a table?**  [I don't want to do it this way because I'd like the numbers to remain sequential and in order when a user adds or deletes a row or if a subset of rows is queried.  I could write code to detect changes and renumber, but I'm hoping for something simpler.]

Comment: Maybe 'RecordSet.AbsolutePosition' can help you out? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823038.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Right now I'm not traversing the record set within VBA.  This is a pure SQL query report where I'm running no code.  I was hoping for a simpler solution.  I can't use Dcount either because my query is joining data across four tables and grouping it.  As a result, I don't have a single ID that is always in order.  [Row numbers in query result using Microsoft Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279320/row-numbers-in-query-result-using-microsoft-access)