# How to reset values of auto number field

Tags: vba

I have a table in MS access having more than 30 thousand rows.But in this table some values are duplicate so i delete duplicate rows and during this process autonumber fields also delete.Now i want to reset existing autonumber values using any query or vba code.

I use below mentioned query for reset values but query starts next value from one not resetting existing values.

```
ALTER TABLE [urlcheck] ALTER COLUMN [ID] COUNTER(1,1);
```

Currently auto number field values are just like this 1,2,5,7,9 now i want to reset values in this format 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: That is the way AutoIncrement fields are supposed to work. And there's nothing wrong with having gaps in the sequence stemming from deleted records. So if there's no actual technical reason to renumber the records, I suggest to leave it as it is. That said, for renumbering all records with an AutoIncrement field, you need to DROP that column from the database and recreate it.

Comment: thanks,but i am facing issue in my next operations.auto number value should be in sequence

Comment: If you drop and recreate the column, Access will renumber all records in sequence. Just try it for yourself manually in Access and see what happens.

Comment: Usually autoincrement fields named`ID`are primary key for table and used as foreign key in other tables. If you change the`ID`you need to change the foreign key. To get a sequence, just count all rows with`ID`smaller than rows you want the number of. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279320/row-numbers-in-query-result-using-microsoft-access