# Keep IDs in sequential order after deleing a row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access Database table, where i use the "Id" value in order to gather the information in that row.

Example:

```
Id   Name      Surname 
1    Jim       Smith   
2    Luis      Evans
3    Charles   Holland
4    John      Price
```

I have a Query which is used to delete one of the rows of this table, however when i delete a row in the table the Id values don't stay in a sequential order. For exmaple if i delete the id 2 row the table will look like this:

```
Id   Name      Surname 
1    Jim       Smith   
3    Charles   Holland
4    John      Price
```

How do i make it so when I delete a row in the table the Ids stay in sequential order? Like this:

```
Id   Name      Surname 
1    Jim       Smith   
2    Charles   Holland
3    John      Price
```

Comment: Is the `Id` field an `AutoNumber` field?

Comment: Yes i think so.

Comment: Is it the primary key? And  why do you need the Id field in sequential order and without gaps.

Comment: Maybe you are after [row numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279320/row-numbers-in-query-result-using-microsoft-access)

Comment: The reason is because i'm using this as a quiz software and i use the ID for each question numer

id = 1 means Question 1.
id = 2 means Question 2.
etc

Comment: Using these automatically (AutoNumber) generated `id` values in your user interface is not, with respect, a good application design. You should either make a separate column with the question number, or have your application retrieve the questions in order by `id`, then apply its own number to each question.

Comment: @O.Jones Yeah i think that might be best to have a seperate question num column. 

I am very new to SQL and i'm only really using it because the project I was given requires the use of a SQL Database. 

What method would you use to keep that ```QuestionNum``` field sequential?

Comment: How to keep those numbers sequential? Don't rely on Access to do that, do it in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-query to get the "question number". Something like this:

```
SELECT Q.ID, Q.ForeName, Q.Surname,
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tblQuestion AS Q1 WHERE Q1.ID<=Q.ID) AS QuestionNo
FROM tblQuestion AS Q
ORDER BY Q.ID ASC;
```

This counts the number of records that have an ID less than or equal to the ID of the current record. So, in the table with 1 record deleted, ID 1 has 1 record (ID 1), ID 3 has two records (ID 1 and 3), and ID 4 has three records (ID 1, 3 and 4).

Note that `Name` is a reserved word, so you should use a different name for the field.

Answer (score -1):

you can get temporary data like this

```
 select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Id) As Id,Name,Surname From TableData
```

Comment: AFAIK, ROW_NUMBER does not exist in JET-SQL.